# Auto-Incrementation in InfoPath 2010 Form

Tags: infopath

I have a form in which I am attaching a workflow to. The form has a number that will be auto-generated. For example the first number will be 1, the next time the form is opened the number should be 2, so on and so forth. The issue I am having is: in the Default Value under the Text Box Properties I have the Value as: count(mynumber QuoteNumber) +1. When the form is generated the first and only number is 2 the number begins at 2 and never increases. Can someone help me with this or explain what I may be doing wrong? Thank You. I'm not using visual studio.

Comment: I am going to retag this - you might be using other technologies, but as the question is written (and needed for an answer) you only need the one main tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong - you just have to change how you think about "forms" a bit. Remember a form is just like a word document template. Suppose you save a word document on your hard drive with a blank spot to fill in your name. Later you open the template, type your name, and save a copy as V1.doc. When you go back and open the template again - your name is not there because it was saved in V1.doc. Everytime you open the template you start again from scratch.

Infopath forms that you design and that the user fills out are templates (.xsn files). When the user fills it out and saves it they are really saving a copy which is only data (.xml files). The .xsn template doesn't change when users interact with it.

So to answer your question - there is no way directly in InfoPath to cleanly keep track of an auto incrementing ID. You will need to tap into some code (webservice, sharepoint, etc) to do that. You could also consider making the ID a GUID (which infopath does support) but it won't be auto incrementing and it won't look "clean" if it has to be displayed/used by real people.

Comment: @ktharsis-Thank you for your help. I was playing with the form again today and trying to push the limit at what I could do and even just having 'count(mynumber QuoteNumber)' 1 displays in the field, but it doesn't increment. The users will be a department we have here. I can at least try to get it to work, try being the main objective as I am still learning ALL of SharePoint and InfoPath and Visio...I'm VERY new to this, but it brings a challenge and a good one at that. Like putting pieces of a puzzle together for the pretty picture. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 2):

Rachel: I have fought with this problem since InfoPath 2007. Here is how I do it.
Since you say you are attaching a workflow, I assume you are using the from in SharePoint.
1 - create your form library in SharePoint

2 - use InfoPath to design the form. When you publish the form to SP, make sure you promote AT LEAST the ID field you want to auto-inc. (I usually promote every field in my forms, 'cause I like to use them like SP lists.)

3 - In SP, create one new form and manually set the ID field to the starting number for your form series.

4 - return to InfoPath designer and re-open your form template.

5 - create a new data source to receive data from your SP form library and specify your form library as the source, and the ID field as a data element. Name the data source something like “ID Lookup”.

6 - open the properties of the field you want to auto-inc on your form and, in the default value box, select function, then choose the MAX function.

And add “+1” after the function to increment by 1.

Now, double-click in the field are of the Max function. You will see a dialog showing your form fields. Notice the drop-down at the top of the dialog – here you can choose the data source (notice I named mine “sales Contracts” in this example). If you select the data source you created in step 5, you will see a dialog showing you a couple of data branches.

Expand the ‘dataFields’ branch until you see the field you want to auto-inc. Click on this.
Your formula dialog will look something like:

max(ID_X0020) + 1

With your field name instead of the 'ID' in the Max function – the function will now return the Maximum value of the field IN THE FORM LIBRARY, plus 1.

Save the form in InfoPath and try previewing it. You will probably get a security warning – your InfoPath form is grabbing data from your SharePoint library on the fly. You may even get asked to re-enter your password (I usually do). When the new, blank form is displayed in InfoPath preview, you should see you ID field filled in with a value one greater that the number in that field of your SP library.

There is one huge Gothca with this method - if users re-open a completed form to edit it, the formula will probably try to replace the ID number. If your users don't edit the forms after they are submitted, the this will work for you.

Hope this makes sense.